# NewtonSoft JsonConvert.SerializeObject, \" added after serializing DateTime

Tags: c#, json, datetime, serialization, json.net

After serializing a datetime property with NewtonSoft, the value went from `2021-02-19 10:00` as DateTime to `\\"2021-02-19T10:00:00\\"` as string. Deserializing failed without replacing those `\\"`. This replace was a quick fix, but now am I curious how this is possible and how I can avoid the replace.

When things are missing in my post, please give me a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of serializing a `DateTime` with `JsonConvert`, you can use one of the standard format strings. The equivalent format to the one the `Serialize` method produces is the [sortable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Sortable) specifier, `s`. So:

```cs
new DateTime(2021, 2, 19, 10, 0, 0).ToString("s")
```

produces:

```
2021-02-19T10:00:00
```

without the quotes.